# How to install CKeditor

Tags: javascript, object, ckeditor

I don't know how to install CKeditor, I downloaded the editor on the website and then put the following code between my head tags :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var oFCKeditor1 = new CKEDITOR('message');
        oFCKeditor1.ToolbarSet = 'Basic' ;
        oFCKeditor1.BasePath = "ckeditor/" ;
        oFCKeditor1.ReplaceTextarea() ;
    }
</script>
```

But the line below returns me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

```
var oFCKeditor1 = new CKEDITOR('message');
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration), include the ckeditor.js file:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
```

The editor operates on `textarea` elements, so create one in your body somewhere:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

Then initialize the editor with the following code **after** the declaration of your `textarea` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was written one article for it on this link. maybe it helps 
Include the js file in your web page. you can also use CKEditor CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

OR

<script src="CKEditor_file_path/ckeditor.js"/>

 After select textarea where you want to add CKEditor

 <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
           This Textarea Replaced By CKEditor.
  </textarea>
```

Write code to replace textarea in CKEditor

```
<script>
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

"editor1" is the name of textarea for more information you can view this blog

http://besticoder.com/how-to-use-ckeditor-in-your-website-for-user-input/

Answer (score 0):

**I have write this type of code. with cdn Link maybe it helps Include the js file in your web page.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).